# Neo4j : Difference between cypher execution and Java API call?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Neo4j : Enterprise version 3.2

I see a tremendous difference between the following two calls in terms for speed. Here are the settings and query/API.

Page Cache : **16g** | Heap : **16g**

Number of row/nodes -> **600K**

cypher code (ignore syntax if any) | **Time Taken : 50 sec**.

```
using periodic commit 10000
load with headers from 'file:///xyx.csv' as row with row
create(n:ObjectTension) set n = row
```

From Java (session pool, with 15 session at time as an example):

Thread_1 : Time Taken : 8 sec / 10K

```
   Map<String,Object> pList = new  HashMap<String, Object>();

   try(Transaction tx = Driver.session().beginTransaction()){
      for(int i = 0; i< 10000; i++){
         pList.put(i, i * i);
         params.put("props",pList);
         String query = "Create(n:Label {props})";
         // String query = "create(n:Label) set n = {props})";
          tx.run(query, params);
   }
```

Thread_2  : Time taken is 9 sec / 10K

```
   Map<String,Object> pList = new  HashMap<String, Object>();
   try(Transaction tx = Driver.session().beginTransaction()){
      for(int i = 0; i< 10000; i++){
         pList.put(i, i * i);
         params.put("props",pList);
         String query = "Create(n:Label {props})";
         // String query = "create(n:Label) set n = {props})";
          tx.run(query, params);
   }
.
.
.
Thread_3 : Basically the above code is reused..It's just an example.
```

Thread_N  where N = (600K / 10K)

Hence, the over all time taken is around 2 ~ 3 mins.

**The question are the following?**

1. How does CSV load handles internally? Like does it open single session and multiple transactions within?

Or

Create multiple session based on the parameter passed as "Using periodic commit 10000", with this 600K/10000 is 60 session? etc

2. What's the best way to write via Java?

The idea is achieve the same write performance as CSV load via Java. As the csv load 12000 nodes in ~5 seconds or even better.

Comment: Assume that the pList if out the try block and the data is filled loaded before the transaction is opened.                                 
    Map<String,Object> pList = new  HashMap<String, Object>();           for(int i = 0; i< 10000; i++){
         pList.put(i, i * i);
         params.put("props",pList); }
   try(Transaction tx = Driver.session().beginTransaction()){
      
         String query = "Create(n:Label {props})";
         // String query = "create(n:Label) set n = {props})";
          tx.run(query, params);
   }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Java code is doing something *very* different than your Cypher code, so it really makes no sense to compare processing times.

You should change your Java code to read from the same CSV file. File IO is fairly expensive, but your Java code is not doing any.

Also, whereas your pure Cypher query is creating nodes with a fixed (and presumably relatively small) number of properties, your Java `pList` is growing in size with every loop iteration -- so that each Java loop creates nodes with between 1 to 10K properties! This may be the main reason why your Java code is much slower.

[UPDATE 1]

If you want to ignore the performance difference between using and not using a CSV file, the following (untested) code should give you an idea of what similar logic would look like in Java. In this example, the `i` loop assumes that your CSV file has 10 columns (you should adjust the loop to use the correct column count). Also, this example gives all the nodes the same properties, which is OK as long as you have not created a contrary uniqueness constraint.

```
Session session = Driver.session();

Map<String,Object> pList = new HashMap<String, Object>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    pList.put(i, i * i);
}

Map<String, Map> params = new HashMap<String, Map>();
params.put("props", pList);

String query = "create(n:Label) set n = {props})";

for (int j = 0; j < 60; j++) {
    try (Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction()) {
        for(int k = 0; k < 10000; k++){
            tx.run(query, params);
        }
    }
}
```

[UPDATE 2 and 3, copied from chat and then fixed]

Since the Cypher planner is able to optimize, the actual internal logic is probably a lot more efficient than the Java code I provided (above). If you want to also optimize your Java code (which may be closer to the code that Cypher actually generates), try the following (untested) code. It sends 10000 rows of data in a single `run()` call, and uses the `UNWIND` clause to break it up into individual rows on the server.

Session session = Driver.session();

```
Map<String, Integer> pList = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  pList.put(Integer.toString(i), i*i);
}

List<Map<String,Integer>> rows = Collections.nCopies(1, pList);

Map<String, List> params = new HashMap<String, List>();
params.put("rows", rows);

String query = "UNWIND {rows} AS row CREATE(n:Label) SET n = {row})";

for (int j = 0; j < 60; j++) {
  try (Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction()) {
    tx.run(query, params);
  }
}
```

Comment: What if pList is prepared before I open a transaction?  The code example shown above was to give an idea of how I divided the in xyz.csv into chunks and to do the same think that CSV Load is doing?                                        My question is basically on the session and transactions. What's the right way to do it.

Comment: It is best not to edit your question in such a way that existing answers and comments make no sense any more. StackOverflow is for the benefit of all who have similar questions, and so we should make sure that the Questions and Answers are in sync. I have restored your original code. If you want to show alternate code, you can add it to your question, and clearly indicate that it is an update to the original question.

Comment: Ok, assume the for loop that loads data into the pList is out of the try block.

Comment: thanks for reply,  which means your asking me to open 60 session? Could talk more in terms of session and transaction. As I want clearly understand the best way.

Comment: Good catch. I have edited my answer to just create a single `Session`. (I'd be curious to hear how this code actually performs.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156508/discussion-between-neoman1-and-cybersam).

Answer (score 0):

You can try are creating the nodes using Java API, instead of relying on Cypher:

- `createNode` - http://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/javadocs/org/neo4j/graphdb/GraphDatabaseService.html#createNode-org.neo4j.graphdb.Label...-
- `setProperty` - http://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/javadocs/org/neo4j/graphdb/PropertyContainer.html#setProperty-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-

Also, as predecessor had mentioned, `props` variable has different values for your cases.

Additionally, notice that every iteration you are performing query parsing (`String query = "Create(n:Label {props})";`) - unless it is optimized out by neo4j itself.